# Can I pool together data from two seperate RCTs of the same intervention when I have access to both datasets? If so, what analysis is appropriate?

Tags: meta-analysis, clinical-trials, pooling, randomized-tests

**Background**

I have available the data from:

1. A parallel arm RCT of **Intervention A** compared to a control group that was conducted several years ago. The primary outcome is a difference in the post-intervention means on an outcome. The statistical model is ANCOVA on the posttest scores with the pretest as a covariate.
2. A parallel arm RCT of **Intervention A** compared to a control group that I conducted recently. The primary outcome is a difference in the post-intervention means on the same outcome. The statistical model is ANCOVA on the posttest scores with the pretest as a covariate.

I would like to pool these data together to increase power and the precision of the parameter estimates. I don't think a meta-analysis is the correct approach as I have a full set of the raw data.

**Question**

Is it appropriate to pool these data together in some way? If so, what statistical model could be used to estimate the treatment effect on the pooled data?

Comment: I think the search term you are looking for is _individual participant data meta-analysis_ usually IPD meta-analysis.

Comment: There is plenty of resources on this topic, but as starting point I recommend this book: https://www.wiley.com/en-am/Individual+Participant+Data+Meta+Analysis%3A+A+Handbook+for+Healthcare+Research-p-9781119333722